# What character is this?

Tags: fonts, characters

Does anyone know what character this is?

[image]

How do I reproduce it in LaTeX? It came from a PDF written with LaTeX (which I obviously don't have the source code for).

Comment: it's probably a double struck O like \mathbb{O} if you have the pdf, pdffonts utility or your viewer font menu will tell you which fonts  are in the pdf

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was able to get a list of fonts in Adobe Acrobat. There are 37 fonts listed. I guess I have to try \mathbb{O} for each font after finding those fonts to use in my LaTeX doc. Any quicker way to isolate this?

Comment: or add the list here and someone will tell you which fonts have double struck characters if you cut and paste the character is it (U+004F) `O` or U+1D546 `` ?

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the list of fonts by not using the while PDF but only one page. Also reducing the list of fonts by eliminating, e.g., bold fonts, sans-serif etc. could help.

Comment: It's almost certainly a double-struck (`\mathbb`} O, but why do you want to know exactly which one?  If your reason is to use the exact same shape, then yes, you do need to know the font (although this could have been constructed from an O and a "placed" vertical rule).  But if you are using other double-struck letters, then I would advise you to use the same font you're using for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `O` is that of `dsfont`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}
$\mathds O$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks **very** similar, thank you!

Comment: @at. You're welcome :-).

Comment: @at. It is actually from bbmbx10. Look at p. 6 of the blackboard.ps file here: https://ctan.org/pkg/blackboard